# Change the App Proxy settings from the PreferenceActivity in real time

Tags: java, android, android-activity, proxy, preferenceactivity

I have MainActivity and PreferencesActivity. PreferencesActivity allow the user switching "use proxy" setting. When i come back from PreferencesActivity to MainActivity i wanna my new settings works right away, but they works only after i close and open the application again.

I set the proxy settings using this method in `onCreate` of MainActivity

```
private void setProxy(String host, String port)
{
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", host);
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", port);
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", host);
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", port);
}
```

It looks like this (simplified code)

```
if(preferences.getBoolean("use_proxy"))
{
    setProxy(proxyHost, proxyPort);
}
else
{
    resetProxy();
}
```

In theory if i would coming back from Preferences Activity to MainActivity using next code it should work

```
Intent intent = new Intent(PreferencesActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
```

But it doesn't. Although  `onCreate` method of MainActivity is executing and set the proxy, but the network doesn't work through the proxy before the application is restarted manually by the user.

Finally I found the only working way, but I'm not sure that it's the right one. I use this code when i close PreferencesActivity and come back to MainActivity

```
PackageManager packageManager = c.getPackageManager();// c - PreferencesActivity context
Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(c.getPackageName());
ComponentName componentName = intent.getComponent();
Intent mainIntent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(componentName);
c.startActivity(mainIntent);
System.exit(0);
```

This works fine, but as far as I know, it's not recommended to use `System.exit (0);` and the use of `finish` doesn't work in this case.

The Question is what is right way to force to work the PreferenceActivity changes without closing application by user, and restart application automatically?

Comment: can you post also the PreferenceActivity and the part of MainActivity where getting the value of proxy? 'coz restarting or closing the application is not necessary when putting and getting the value of your preferenceActivity.

Comment: @Jerrol Yes, look here please, I've placed some of the code in google documents so as not to expand this question https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OYrJPNP0EynyUvpJKm1124F5E2mKdVer-wG8v7qCxLA/edit?usp=sharing

and also I've captured the video where I'm debugging the application (on video it has worked one time on 3:33 but only in debug mode) - https://youtu.be/QLRa2yHtDWQ
I'll explain a little: if the check box "use proxy" is not selected, the data without the proxy should not be loaded, otherwise everything should work without any problem

Answer (score 0):

[onCreate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) - Called when the activity is first created. This is where you should do all of your normal static set up: create views, bind data to lists, etc. This method also provides you with a Bundle containing the activity's previously frozen state, if there was one.

[onResume](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()) - Called when the activity will start interacting with the user. At this point your activity is at the top of the activity stack, with user input going to it.

So if you wan't to get the value you set from your `PreferenceActivity` try to place this statement in `onResume()` instead in `onCreate()`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //.. 
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(preferences.contains("use_custom_proxy_settings_key") &&
         preferences.getBoolean("use_custom_proxy_settings_key", false)) {
              if(preferences.contains("custom_proxy_host_key") &&
                    !preferences.getString("custom_proxy_host_key", proxyHost).isEmpty() &&
                    preferences.contains("custom_proxy_port_key") &&
                    !preferences.getString("custom_proxy_port_key", proxyPort).isEmpty() )
              proxyHost = preferences.getString("custom_proxy_host_key", proxyHost);
              proxyPort = preferences.getString("custom_proxy_port_key", proxyPort);
    }

    if (preferences.contains("use_proxy_key") && preferences.getBoolean("use_proxy_key", false))
    {
          Log.d("MainActivity proxy set","proxyHost: "+ proxyHost + ", proxyPort: " + proxyPort);
          setProxy(proxyHost, proxyPort);
    }
    else
    {
        resetProxy();
          //setProxy("", "");
          Log.d("MainActivity proxy set","proxyHost: "+ System.getProperties()
            .getProperty("https.proxyHost") +
            ", proxyPort: " + System.getProperties().getProperty("https.proxyPort"));
    }
}
```

> just start the intent without any `flags`, `startActivity(new Intent(this,
>   PreferenceActivity.class));`

Comment: Sorry but you did not understand what is the problem. In my case activity was executing from begin and the OnCreate method was executing after i comming back from PreferenceActivity, and proxy settings was setting, but didnt work. And i've found what was a problem. It was my mistake. When i was comming back from PreferencesActivity i had AsyncTask with old request who was working and i just should had stoppend him and restart after i setted proxy params.

Comment: But the second problem is when i am disabling proxy it is not disabling, and next requests is sending, but should not. I think it's deeper than it seems. resetProxy function is described in the question. I think it would be better to create new question for it

Comment: @VladPylyp Hey, did you find any solution on above problem? Have you got any success for disabling proxy? If so, then please share your solution as we are also dealing with the similar case.

Comment: @Mrug sorry I did not find any solution other than the solution I described in the question